# Argument of type 'Date | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Date>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, react-datepicker

I am following the [Ionic tutorial for react](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/your-first-app).
I created the tutorial page and I am trying to add a datepicker element to it. This is my page right now:

```
import { IonContent, IonHeader, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar } from '@ionic/react';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker'
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

const Home: React.FC = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle>Ionic Blank</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent className="ion-padding">
        The world is your oyster 14.
        <p>
          If you get lost, the{' '}
          <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://ionicframework.com/docs/">
            docs
          </a>{' '}
          will be your guide.
        </p>
        <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} />
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The datepicker that I am using is from [here](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-today-button) and I used the first example in my page:

```
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} />
  );
};
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
[react-scripts] Argument of type 'Date | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Date>'.
[react-scripts]   Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Date>'.  TS2345
[react-scripts]     22 |           will be your guide.
[react-scripts]     23 |         </p>
[react-scripts]   > 24 |         <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} />
[react-scripts]        |                                                                         ^
[react-scripts]     25 |       </IonContent>
[react-scripts]     26 |     </IonPage>
[react-scripts]     27 |   );
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `onChange` callback from `react-datepicker` looks like [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/160b87bfbf759f34ddcaf96d528397092270500a/types/react-datepicker/index.d.ts#L79):

```
onChange(date: Date | null, event: React.SyntheticEvent<any> | undefined): void;
```

So `date` potentially can be `null`. You have two options here:

---

1.) accept nullable date state in `useState` Hook:

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date | null>(new Date());
```

2.) only invoke `setStartDate`, when `date` is not null:

```
<DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={date => date && setStartDate(date)} />
```

Comment: I get a weird one in 2021 now, Type 'Date | [Date | null, Date | null] | null' is not assignable to type 'Date | null | undefined'. for "selected" prop even .. hmmph? does not seem right, why not? :D

Answer (score 9):

Update for same issue in 2021

```
<DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={(date: Date | null) => setStartDate(date)} />
```

Does the job

Comment: nope, still getting: `Argument of type 'Date | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Date>'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<Date>`

Comment: Yes because you have set your state like that

const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date | null>useState(null)

in the case you plan to have "null" value

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late to join the party, I just got the DatePicker working.
Following is the working code:

```
const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date>(new Date());
<DatePicker
   selected={startDate}
   onChange={(date: Date) => setStartDate(date!)}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date|null>(new Date());
  return (
    <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={(date: Date | null) => setStartDate(date)} />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone who get the error:

> Type 'Date | [Date | null, Date | null] | null' is not assignable to type 'Date | null | undefined

That's because you are using date range so onChange argument will get an array type [start, end].